# How can I determine the correct number of YARN containers?

Tags: hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

My question is about the configuration of YARN.
How can I determine how many containers I need in my cluster? 
In other words, what have i to consider to set the correct amount of memory/cpu per container?

There are some best practices for the sizing?

Thanks.

Comment: was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't comment from a hortonworks, but the sizing should be the same as cloudera

**CPU**

1 vcore dedicated to the os
1 vcore to the hdfs datanode
1 vcore for the node manager
1 vcore for the vendor agent (this is purely for cloudera, assume there is an ambari equivalent)

All the others I would assign to yarn containers.  I would assign a vcore multiplayer to 4

**RAM**

Reserve some for you OS, it depends on your os but it would be between 4-8GB
take away ram for your hdfs datanode & your nodemanager (min 1gb each) 
Take away any additional ram reserved for other services
Assign the rest for yarn.